# MySQli returns double results

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm still very new in using mySQli and php, currently I'm using a simple mySQli query

```
$datas = $mysqli->query("SELECT firstname FROM Customer");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($datas)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

However the result that returns is double, is it normal?

```
 Array
(
[0] => Vincent
[firstname] => Vincent
)
Array
(
[0] => Carmen
[firstname] => Carmen
)
Array
(
[0] => James
[firstname] => James
)
Array
(
[0] => William
[firstname] => William
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results are not 'double'. You get 4 records back from the database, but the way print_r prints them looks a bit like they are 'double'. You can do something like this to show the 1st/0 column:

```
print_r($row[0]);
```

or this to print the column 'firstname':

```
print_r($row['firstname']);
```

which is obviously the same.

**Update**

If you want to loop through all the column you could the do something like this inside you `while` loop:

```
$length = count($row);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  print $row[$i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I (SELECT * FROM Customer), will I be able to print out all the rows without being double or I have to use something else instead of print_r()?

Comment: Usually you should just select the columns you actually need and don't use the *. But if you really want all of them, you can make a small for loop from 0 to the the number of columns in your row and use the counter as an column index.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful

Comment: I've added an basic example with a loop

Answer (score 2):

You don't get twice the number of records. You get the same data, but you get it both as associative and numerical array. This is because you have used [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php), which by default returns an array indexed both by numerical key and the name of the DB column from `SELECT`.
To get the result as an associative array only use one of the following:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($datas, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    print_r($row);
}
// or
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datas)) {
    print_r($row);
}
// or
foreach ($datas as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

To get the result as a numerical array only use one of the following:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($datas, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    print_r($row);
}
// or
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($datas)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```